# Deleting Checked rows from gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-4.0

I have a gridview which is binded to the datasource.In that gridview i have one column of checkboxes.I want to delete the rows of gridview by checking the checkbox of particular rows,Finally i have delete button outside the gridview which deletes the checked rows from the gridview.

problem is even though am checking checkboxes of rows..but it's showing checked=false...so none of the rows am able t delete..i tried all the possibilities but its not working

Please give me solution ASAP
this is my code

```
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {

        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)row.Cells[5].FindControl("chkDelete");

            if (chkDelete != null)
            {
                if (chkDelete.Checked)//It Showing checked=false
```

{
//delete code goes here//

Answer (score 0):

Check you page load event, grid view may be rebinding again on each Postbacks. If you found such scenario, make following changes in your code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
     //logic on page load
 }
}
```